# Application.Volatile crashes excel on close

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function which is marked as volatile. This function is called in a formula and is executed everytime a cell in the formula is updated.

I noticed excel crashing after the Workbook_BeforeClose() event. Upcon commenting the Applicaiton.volatile() in the function excel did not crash anymore.

Is there a particular way volatile functions should be handled?

Formula that calls the Volatile Function is on Sheet3:

```
=IF(C2="","",IF(OR(...,...,...,...),"Invalid",IF(AND(C2="...",...),"Valid",IF(AND(C2=...,E2<=...),"Valid",IF(AND(C2=...,E2<=...),"Valid",IF(IsIndustryCodeValid(),"Valid","Invalid"))))))
```

Volatile Function:

```
Public Function IsIndustryCodeValid() As Boolean
    Application.Volatile
    Dim ValidIndustryCodes() As Variant, IndustryCode As String

    ValidIndustryCodes = Array(33,46,45)
    IndustryCode = Left(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2"), 2)
    i = 0
    For i = LBound(ValidCodes) To UBound(ValidCodes)
        If IndustryCode = ValidIndustryCodes (i) Then
            IsIndustryCodeValid = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Workbook BeforeClose Code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        .Unprotect Password:="password"

            For i = 2 To 10
                If Not .Range("C" & i) = vbNullString Then
                    .Range("C" & i).Locked = True
                End If
            Next i

        .Protect Password:="password"
    End With

End Sub
```

Note: Its the volatile function which crashes and not the Workbook_Close(). I know this because commenting the Workbook_Close() crashes excel on close. Wherease commenting Application.Volatile does not crash excel on close.

Comment: **Help us to help you.**  Post your code.

Comment: Post both the codes `Workbook_BeforeClose()` and `Function` which has `Applicaiton.volatile()`

Comment: @SiddharthRout I added the code above

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I added the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe (and I could be wrong) but the reason for the crash is that the workbook is not able to finish all the calculation and save the workbook and hence it is crashing.

You need to give Excel the time to finish what it is doing. Try this. Change your `Workbook_BeforeClose` to this.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Unprotect Password:="password"
            For i = 2 To 10
                If Not .Range("C" & i) = vbNullString Then
                    .Range("C" & i).Locked = True
                End If
            Next i
        .Protect Password:="password"
    End With
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    DoEvents
End Sub
```